# How to make a custom annotation in Java that would allow parameters to have a value from a specified range?

Tags: java, annotations

I want to create an annotation that can be applied only to method parameters and should specify the range of values that parameters can accept.

Lets say I have an annotation `@MyAnnotation` and it accepts values from 0 to 255.

Now if I have the following method

```
public boolean isInRange(@MyAnnotation int value) {
.......
.......
}
```

and some class tries to call it the following way:

`isInRange(300);`

I want the annotation to give a warning saying the value is not acceptable and should be in the range (showing the range). I also don't want the compiler to compile it until correct value is passed to the method.

Now I know that `@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)` causes the annotation to be applied only to parameters, but I don't know how to implement the range logic and also if the RetentionPolicy should be `RetentionPolicy.SOURCE` or `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`

Comment: What if someone does `isInRange(someMethodThatReturnsAnInt());`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth In that case, the execution should throw an exception printing a clear message. But I still want the annotation to give warning when the value is being typed

Answer (score 1):

The [`@IntRange`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/common/value/qual/IntRange.html) annotation of the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/).  Does this.  The [Constant Value Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#constant-value-checker) enforces the property at compile time -- that is, the compiler warns you if a client of the method could pass an illegal value.

You could re-use that annotation, or study its implementation if you want your own annotation.